# Taking a column and converting to counts per id in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have these two datasets, related to a call center:

```
my_call <- data.frame(id = c(1:6),
                      call_id = c(rep(200,3),rep(300,3)),
                      result = c("answering machine","call back","call_back",
                                 "still workable","transfer call","do not call"),
                      code_result = c("am","cb","cb","sw","tc","dc"))

my_lead <- data.frame(lead_id = c(200,300),
                      lead_source = c("bpos","zeta"))

> my_call
  id call_id            result code_result
1  1     200 answering machine          am
2  2     200         call back          cb
3  3     200         call_back          cb
4  4     300    still workable          sw
5  5     300     transfer call          tc
6  6     300       do not call          dc

> my_lead
  lead_id lead_source
1     200        bpos
2     300        zeta
```

I want to join these two datasets, by `call_id` and `lead id`, but I want that `code_result` to pivot wider so as to count the results per id. This is the expected result:

```
  lead_id lead_source am cb sw tc dc
1     200        bpos 1  2  0  0  0
2     300        zeta 0  0  1  1  1
```

I think a left join could be ok but I'm stuck in how to do it, and if I have to type all the results `(am, cb, sw, tc, dc)` or if it's possible that R can do it automatically. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join and cast the data to wide format -

```
library(dplyr)  
library(tidyr)
  
left_join(my_call, my_lead, by = c('call_id' = 'lead_id')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = code_result, values_from = code_result,
              values_fn = length, values_fill = 0, 
              id_cols = c(call_id, lead_source))

#  call_id lead_source    am    cb    sw    tc    dc
#    <dbl> <chr>       <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     200 bpos            1     2     0     0     0
#2     300 zeta            0     0     1     1     1
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Shah, just a question related to the answer below, you used `length` and Karthik S used `Count`, is there any substancial difference?

Comment: Yes. Note that I have used `length` in `values_fn` whereas Karthik has used `Count` in `values_from` . In my answer I refer to `length` as a function whereas `Count` is the column name in Karthik's answer.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you Ronak, have a great day!

Comment: Upvoted.  The other two answers are just adding extra steps instead of doing it in `pivot_wider` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
my_call %>% inner_join(my_lead, by = c('call_id' = 'lead_id')) %>% 
   group_by(call_id, code_result,lead_source) %>% summarise(Count = n()) %>% 
   pivot_wider(id_cols = c(call_id,lead_source), names_from = code_result, values_from = Count ) %>% 
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace_na(., 0)))
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'call_id', 'code_result'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 2 x 7
# Groups:   call_id [2]
  call_id lead_source    am    cb    dc    sw    tc
    <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     200 bpos            1     2     0     0     0
2     300 zeta            0     0     1     1     1
```

Comment: Thank you @Karthik S, I saw you used across everything, does that mean that any NA will be replaced, doesn't it?

Comment: @Alexis, yes NAs will be replaced by 0s.

Comment: I must be careful then with that replacement! Thank you Karthik, have a great day!

Comment: @KarthikS, you can use `values_fill` argument instead of adding one extra step

Comment: @AnilGoyal, yes, didn't occur to me then and only realized after seeing Ronak's reply. But didn't change my code as that additional step can act as a takeaway in other scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of good answers already, but you can also use `count()` rather than `group_by` and `summarise`, and `values_fill` argument in `pivot_wider`

```
my_lead %>% inner_join(my_call, by = c("lead_id" = "call_id")) %>% 
  count(lead_id,code_result, lead_source) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "code_result", values_from = "n", values_fill = 0)
```

Comment: That's a great approach @awaji98, just a doubt, is `count` a member of the tidy verse or a Base R function?

Comment: But awaji98, that is also not needed, if that can be done easily in `values_fn` argument of `pivot_wider`